# Функция считывания данных со строки текстового файла C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста функцию считывания аргументов со строки файла. В строке находятся два целочисленных числа   разделенные пробелом, строка завершается символом перехода к новой строке. Как считать эти два числа в отдельные переменные, не используя функций с библиотеки string?

Comment: Для функций форматированного чтения потока в С++ не существует понятия "строки". Поэтому если для вас критично "видеть" разбиение на строки, то - только `getline` и затем ручной парсинг строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если входной поток - `input`, то

```
int a, b;
input >> a >> b;
```

Можно для сброса буфера ввода добавить

```
input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double s1,s2;
ifstream fin(FILE_NAME, ios::in);
fin >> s1 >>s2;
```

Предварительно подключить библиотеку